# Multiple confusion matrices with plot_confusion_matrix

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I want plot three consufusion_matrix in the same windows.
I used plot_confusion_matrix becouse i have a np.array to indicate the data of consusion matrix (I took some confusion matrix and i have do some  operation with they).

When i plot don't see the label in each one.

```
    a1 = np.zeros(shape=(19, 19))  
    a2 = np.zeros(shape=(19, 19))  
    a3 = np.zeros(shape=(19, 19))  

    for element in total_cm_svm:
        a1 = a1 + element

    for element in total_cm_lda:
        a2 = a2 + element

    for element in total_cm_etc:
        a3 = a3 + element


    fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3)

    cm = plot_confusion_matrix(conf_mat=a1, colorbar=False, class_names=label_ax, axis=axes[0])
    cm1 = plot_confusion_matrix(conf_mat=a2, colorbar=False, class_names=label_ax, axis=axes[1])
    cm2 = plot_confusion_matrix(conf_mat=a3, colorbar=False, class_names=label_ax, axis=axes[2])
 
    plt.show()
```

`total_cm_svm`, `total_cm_lda` and `in total_cm_etc` are list which contain confusion_matrix elements (`confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred, labels=label_ax)`)

[image]
I would like to indicate labels = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18'] and indicate name of axis in each one plot

Comment: `for ax in axes:` with `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(matplotlib.ticker.MultipleLocator(1))` and similar for `y`.  You can use `axes[0].set_title("total cm svm")` to set a title (or `axes[0].set_xlabel(...)` for an x label).

Comment: The result is good but not that I want, because the label of axes are external to the matrix. I would like the labels as like as in the third plot.